# Axon Framework - is it possible to have a single tracking event processor for multiple sagas?

Tags: java, axon

Let's start of by saying that I'm using version 3.1.2 of Axon Framework with tracking event processors enabled for both `@EventHandlers` and Sagas.

The current default behaviour for creating event processors for Sagas, as I'm seeing it, is to create a single tracking event processor for a single Saga. This works quite well on a microservice scale, but might turn out to be a problem in big monolithic applications which may implement a lot of Sagas. Since I'm writing such application, I want to have a better control over number of running threads, which in turn will give me better control over usage of database connection pool, context switching and memory usage. Ideally, I would like to have as many tracking event processors as CPU cores where each event processor executes multiple sagas and/or `@EventHandlers`.

I have already figured that I'm able to do that for `@EventHandlers` via either `@ProcessingGroup` annotation or `EventHandlingConfiguration::assignHandlersMatching` method, but `SagaConfiguration` does not seem to expose similar API. In fact, the most specific `SagaConfiguration::trackingSagaManager` method is hardcoded to create a new `TrackingEventProcessor` object, which makes me think what I'm trying to achieve is currently impossible. So here's my question: Is there some non-straightforward way that I'm missing which will let me execute multiple Sagas in the context of a single event processor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm with you that it is (currently) not possible to have multiple Sagas be managed by a single`EventProcessor`. Added to that, I'm doubting about the pro's and con's to doing so, as your scenario doesn't sound to weird at first glance.
I recommend to drop a feature request on the AxonFramework GitHub [page](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/issues). That way we (1) document this idea/desire and (2) have a good place to discuss whether to implement this or not.